# Is there a supernatural rat like this?

Tags: mythical-creatures

I had this weird dream including some kind of ghost rats, at first there was this noise they make that was like an indication that the ghost rats were there.

You can not see them and you can only hear them. When they attack they show themselves for a bit to be able to bite people. I think they’re intangible when theyre invisible so they cant be affected and can not affect people. So the only way to kill them was when they appear to attack people, and a single bite kills you in seconds.

So is there a creature like that in lores and legends? I am actually so curious about them right now.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is the Moonrat in my Dungeons and Dragons Monster Manual. They use the power of the moon to become intelligent armies. I've always seen Dungeons and Dragons as legends and folklore in disguise.

Comment: The only rat in folklore that I know of is the [Rat king](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rat_king). It is not related to your ghost rat but can also fuel some nightmares.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but I had a dream about ghost rats.  They weren't hostile and glowed with a faint green.  When I woke up I realized my brain had borrowed them from a family of glow-in-the-dark, plastic rats I have.